# Posting a javascript variable to PHP.

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a javascript function to count the number of clicks. I wish to post the variable storing the count to PHP. I'm unsure why when I submit the form, the count is not echoed out. Below is the HTML file.

```
<html> 
<head>
<title> js php </title>
<script>
    var cnt=0;
    function CountFun(){
    cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
    var divData=document.getElementById("showCount");
    divData.innerHTML="Number of Downloads: ("+cnt +")";//this part has been edited

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="showCount"></div>
<form action "submitClicks.php"id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="numberOfClicks" />
    <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click me" onclick="CountFun()"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Clicks" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then this is my submit clicks page:

```
<?php
    $number_of_clicks = $_POST["cnt"];
    echo $number_of_clicks;
?>
```

Does this implementation look correct to you as when I click submit clicks, nothing happens. I'm expecting the number of clicks to be echoed.

Comment: what does "nothing happens" mean? do you see anything? is it everytime zero or what?

Comment: @t_01 when i click "click me" the number is counted and displayed. When i submit the clicks, the url changed from http://localhost/clicks/count.html to http://localhost/clicks/count.html?numberOfClicks= but the echo with the number of clicks is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action "submitClicks.php"id="form">
```

Should be:

```
<form action="submitClicks.php" id="form" method="post">
```

And shouldn't you have something like:

In HTML:

```
<input id="count" type="hidden" name="cnt" value="">
```

In your Javascript CountFun function:

```
document.getElementById('count').value = cnt;
```

Comment: This simply removes the data from the URL, which isn't really an issue. I'm trying to have the cnt javascript variable echoed in the PHP file.

Comment: I edited my post. At no point in your code do you actually add the value of the count to be submitted by the form.

Comment: @joemartin if you don't specify that you want to use post, you can't use _POST in your php.

Comment: Hm. With these changes to the code, nothing changes to the output. I still get a counter when I click the "click me" button but when I click "submit clicks", the count isn't echod in the PHP file.

Comment: I edited my answer, it should work now. If it doesn't work, please edit your post with your updated code so we can look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<html> 
<head>
<title> js php </title>
    <script>
        var cnt=0;
        function CountFun(){
        cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
        var divData=document.getElementById("showCount");
        divData.value=cnt;//this part has been edited
        document.getElementById("JustShow").innerHTML= cnt;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="JustShow"></div>
<form action="submitClicks.php" id="form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="showCount" name="cnt" value="0" />
    <input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click me" onclick="CountFun()"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Clicks" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This puts the cnt in the URL bar when I submit the clicks but the PHP gives this error : $number_of_clicks = $_POST["cnt"]; instead of the echo.

Comment: Just change form tag to : <form action="submitClicks.php" id="form" method="post">